# Wrapping divs in a row with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The `div class="col-md-3"` are created dynamically. And I want them to wrap down after four divs are created. If i delete any div I want them to wrap up again.

Is this possible?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid black; min-height:50px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
        culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid black; min-height:50px;"></div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid black; min-height:50px;"></div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid black; min-height:50px;">
        Duis aute irure dolor in
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
        culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid black; min-height:50px;">
    This should be placed under the first 4 divs.
</div>
```

Now It looks liks this. And that's not what I want.
[image: Now It looks liks this.]

Comment: why did you put col-md12 insode the col-md-3 ?

Comment: I have just fixed that! Sorry! Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: do you want to have something like this (make rendered part full screen to see the effect)? http://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/he3fzkhn/

Comment: yes exactly, so I need to add a new `div` with `row` class? But how can I do that dynamically after four `div` has been added?

Comment: I will write the details in answers, 1 sec.

Comment: thanks, maybe I should also notice that I'm using a handlebar template when adding the new `div` from js.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with help of bootstrap's rows. First of all no need to give min-height:50px to a div. Secondly Boostrap is based on 12 column grid, which means if the sum of columns in a row extends 12 then the new column will go down.
For 
    col-md-3 + col-md-9=col-md-12 or col-md-4+col-md-4+col-md-4 = col-md-12.

If you want to have not more than 4 columns then you should write:

```
col-md-3 + col-md-3 + col-md-3 + col-md-3
```

and this will form a row.

You can make experiments here: http://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/he3fzkhn/

In case you want to remove a certain div from a row and make others to substitute it then you can use a masonry jquery plugin which works very well with bootstrap.

A good references can be found here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-tabs-play-nice-with-masonry/

http://www.bootply.com/123353

Comment: thanks for the answer, I know how to deal with the columns. The problem is, let's say that I want to delete the second `div` in the first row then the last `div` should wrap to the first row.

Comment: you can try a masonry plugin with bootstrap, it allows to set a multiple divs in one row and whenever you remove a certain div then next ones are coming back.

Comment: I just edited answer and added links, but you can check this page which is done with the help of bootstrap and masonry plugin: http://karennersisyan.com/nights.php  whenever you remove a certain div then next ones are coming back.